# difference between data and import in terraform

Tags: cloud, terraform

Hi I am a beginner in Terraform.

While using it I am bit confused about using the existing infrastructure as data and using import command. Because I imported the existing infra and I lost my subnet and keypair and It will be helpful if someone explain how wisely we can use it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The current implementation of Terraform import can only **import** resources into the state. It does not generate configuration.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html

When importing resources you should have the configuration already created so terraform doesn't destroy resource.s

`terraform import resource id`

`terraform plan -out=tfplan.out`

The plan will output what changes it is making to resources, yellow for modify, green new, red destroy.

> -out=path - The path to save the generated execution plan. This plan can then be used with terraform apply to be certain that only the changes shown in this plan are applied. Read the warning on saved plans below.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#out-path

`terraform apply tfplan.out`

Data sources return attributes about the resources for example if the subnet id was the only known, a data source can pull the other information about it, like VPC id.

```
variable "subnet_id" {}

data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  id = "${var.subnet_id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "subnet" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_subnet.selected.vpc_id}"

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = ["${data.aws_subnet.selected.cidr_block}"]
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }
}
```

> The arguments of this data source act as filters for querying the available subnets in the current region. The given filters must match exactly one subnet whose data will be exported as attributes.
>
> availability_zone - (Optional) The availability zone where the subnet must reside.
>
> cidr_block - (Optional) The cidr block of the desired subnet.
>
> ipv6_cidr_block - (Optional) The Ipv6 cidr block of the desired subnet
>
> default_for_az - (Optional) Boolean constraint for whether the desired subnet must be the default subnet for its associated availability zone.
>
> filter - (Optional) Custom filter block as described below.
>
> id - (Optional) The id of the specific subnet to retrieve.
>
> state - (Optional) The state that the desired subnet must have.
>
> tags - (Optional) A mapping of tags, each pair of which must exactly match a pair on the desired subnet.
>
> vpc_id - (Optional) The id of the VPC that the desired subnet belongs to.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet.html

Comment: Hi Bro, Thank you very much for explaining and its very clear. Thanks again.